# Zend Framework 2 - Form Validation from multiple input filters sets?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, models

My ZF2 uses the simple structure I've seen everywhere, with inputFilters set in the models and applied to a form during validation. But I've really hit a wall here. How do you handle validation for a form that has some fields that need validated against one model and some fields that need validated against another ?

My scenario: I am using a single form to insert 2 entries in 2 tables of my database (adding a user, and adding a donation linked to that user). Some fields will go in one table, some others in a second table.

Like I said, my input filters are stored at model-level.

If my whole scenario was involving just one model/table,  for example storing one donation and nothing else, I would go as follow :

```
$donation = new Donation();

$form->setInputFilter($donation->getInputFilter());
$form->setData($request->getPost());

if ($form->isValid()) {

$donation->exchangeArray($form->getData());
$this->getDonationTable()->saveDonation($donation);
```

I can do the above.

But I am trying to analyse and validate the form data against two sets of inputFilters that I am gathering from 2 models. One for the data that will go to a donation model and one for the data that will go to a user. I am therefore after something like this:

```
$donation = new Donation();
$user = new User();

$form->setInputFilter($donation->getInputFilter());
```

Then I would add something like :(obviously doesn't exist)

**$form->addInputFilter($user->getInputFilter());**

So I could continue with ...

```
$form->setData($request->getPost());

if ($form->isValid()) {

    // add donation
    // add user
```

I am surprised I haven't found anything about this on the internet, is the way I am using models and inputFilters incorrect ? How do you handle validation for a form that has some fields that need validated against one model and some fields that need validated against another ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fieldsets** (Form Collections) are what you are looking for. Official documentation is here:

https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html